# K&R Error: conflicting method definition

Tags: c, stdio, kernighan-and-ritchie

I am going through K&R (2 ed.) to learn C as I've been trying to get a basis in lower-level languages to help my programming and also because I want to know C. The book is absolutely fantastic; however, a program they provided on pp. 29 (Sec 1.9 Character Arrays) does not compile. This is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000    /* maximum input line size */

int getline(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

/* print longest input line */
main()
{
    int len;            /* current line length */
    int max;            /* maximum length seen so far */
    char line[MAXLINE];     /* current input line */
    char longest[MAXLINE];  /* longest line saved here */

    max = 0;
    while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
    if (max > 0)    /* there was a line */
        printf("%s", longest);
    return 0;
}

/* getline:  read a line int s, return length */
int getline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    for (i = 0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

/* copy:  copy 'from' into 'to'; assume to is big enough */
void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}
```

When I run `cc longest_line.c` (that's what I called it) I get an error that `getline` has conflicting definitions as it was already defined in `stdio.h`. My question is, how do I resolve this/can I resolve this without giving `getline` a different name?

Comment: For your reference [this is the `getline`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) declared in `<stdio.h>`. As for your problem there is no solution other than to rename your function, you can not have two symbols with the same name and two differing declarations.

Comment: You can change your operating system to a non-posix flavor or you can rename the function.  One of them is fastest.

Comment: 1) C does not support _methods_, only _functions_ 2) K&R teaches an outdated, non-standard compliant version of the C language. Use a more recent book.

Comment: @Olaf is there a real difference between *method*s and *function*s? I've generally heard that they were interchangeable.

Comment: If this conflict exists then why is it in the book.Was't it tested before going into the book.

Comment: @HansPassant is there anyway I can have my OS compile with a non-POSIX style compiler w/o changing my OS to a non-POSIX OS?

Comment: Don't use the same name as standard libray names. What is the problem with simply renaming that function, e.g. to `my_getline`?

Comment: @GauravSehgal: 1) `getline` is POSIX, not C 2) K&R is simply outdated.

Comment: @Olaf I know that's possible, that's not what I'm asking. I'm asking if there is a way to still call the function `getline`.

Comment: @EliSadoff: That is a matter of the library, not the compiler. Just rename and stop trying to outsmart your toolchain!

Comment: @xvan I'm using the second edition. (ANSI-C)

Comment: @EliSadoff: C89/90 is not standard since 17 years now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115315/discussion-between-eli-sadoff-and-olaf).

Comment: CV for typo. Childish "but I don't want to rename it" leads nowhere.

Comment: And instead of `copy`, use `strcpy` or one of its relatives. If that is from the book: this is another example of outdated code, as `from` should be `const char from[]`. Today focus on programming has shifted twards quality. Even more for unsafe languages like C.

Comment: Why are you trying to learn C from a book published in 1988? It's a historical curiosity. Put it on a shelf and get a book that covers the modern language.

Comment: In my copy of Kernighan & Ritchie (1st edition), the code in section 1.9 does not include the statement `#include <stdio.h>`. This is an early chapter in the book and I believe the authors are illustrating their point by including code that would become part of the standard libraries. Try compiling it without the `#include <stdio.h>` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Olaf commented, `getline()` is standard POSIX,

K&R second edition is ansi 89 standard.

Just compile in ansi mode, to prevent the collision with POSIX libraries:

```
gcc -ansi source.c
```

---

Edit:
[GodBot Link](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!%28%28compiler:g6,options:%27-ansi%27,sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4DOAXOID2A6ACwD4AoYRAM3GQFkBBADQBkBJAOQFEkBGABn6SCkAegBUSALYBDAB4gJMCUnAAHGBiRRqSNCABeyUcJIlwGgOYIMWsAgAUEAlIBOm6gG0AugBplYDdIyNggAlADcJABuOCBwSBA4KgCeDk6uGDhevo4uSBTOOBJe4SZiSCrOZpo4YJaYfmoawUhGJNLgdiEkAN4kQn5NCGBh/aNCZRAwzs5DTdpQQ%2BYYBC3G/VWBI2OjZYHyipqLyzoIQzo4ebmt/Tmuwe70zOwcnlvj4pPTsw3qbrarfSEt2qtQQmAejFYnFegjKUBqdTm/zQUkiCDiBAQMwBgMEgSQAF4kLwIv0AO4EEALJB2OwLMCEpCWazUOnUXyPKEcEIhJBEYldbbKCg0%2Bl8ySyXm9IX9fFE%2BmkmWCBLJOkIsEYXzBEpCgC%2BuOFNPx/N4vPeSGWWOQZKkaCQUj%2BhjW2wqZgodgARABSNAerXqzA6oQzDBTBkkkj6khlZnBABcghmUjiDuaVTQvhDYcOtWOrSqsdZwLQWQGbgkXWlQiqEF8IAiBooOFcdhAjJJyhQWgkAFpuEgAGQDmkQAnM26dEIAQgJHAA8gAxQfDiAzgDkAB0wGuRgBqXcgQXbEsgTyMiCKwQgEUOQlEzfbqUG/ons9Ei/PoT7%2BsG/Uv9ynoym68DuBpZs4DI/lGEyJEkCbxLBSBrvkhRrgMFxrhkO72mgaCKMgGTKHaABGIDmEgQw4DA5grK00SxAhqrAhkpbAihRSeJWBpVD%2B3HtpeSAUlSyC0ixgFEuxAGcUgM5IRuIFHmM34RLqQAA%29%29,filterAsm:%28commentOnly:!t,labels:!t%29,version:3)

Comment: What's your toolchain, the code compiles on (x86 gcc), tested multiple gcc versions from 4.8 to 6.1

Comment: gcc: 4.2.1 and LLVM: 7.3.0

Comment: I tried on my computer in both `gcc-4.8` and `gcc-6` but it still doesn't compile.

Comment: Try a newer compiler 4.2.1 is from 2008, I don't know the proper flags on that version, probably you need something else to explicitly disable posix, the earliest I was able to test on godbot is 4.4.7

Comment: This is as far as I can help, something may be wrong with your toolchains. At least on linux x64, it works ok for me.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm going to accept your answer because despite it not working for me, it seems like it should work.

Answer (score -2):

This approach avoids your problem by not including the problematic header. Rather, it copies all the declarations needed in your implementation locally.
This is a very bad idea because the declarations of these functions may change without your knowledge in which case your code will pass or receive bad inputs

```
#define MAXLINE 1000    /* maximum input line size */

int getline(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);
int printf(const char *format, ...);
int getchar(void);

/* print longest input line */
int main()
{
    int len;            /* current line length */
    int max;            /* maximum length seen so far */
    char line[MAXLINE];     /* current input line */
    char longest[MAXLINE];  /* longest line saved here */

    max = 0;
    while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
    if (max > 0)    /* there was a line */
        printf("%s", longest);
    return 0;
}

/* getline:  read a line int s, return length */
int getline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    for (i = 0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=-1 && c!='\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

/* copy:  copy 'from' into 'to'; assume to is big enough */
void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}
```

~

Comment: The OP wants to know if he can avoid renaming `getline`.

Comment: I know that. I was asking if I can keep the definition of `getline` and somehow override `stdio.h`'s definition.

Comment: **Never** declare functions of the standard library yourself! They might be actually macros, have implementation-specific attributes, etc. Use the standard headers. OP shall rename her function.

Comment: @Olaf, this is a specific example and the only possible way to get what the op wants, not everything is black or white. It is clearly mentioned there

Comment: @EliSadoff Does this answer your question Eli?

Comment: @IshayPeled: How does that change what I wrote in my comment?

Comment: @Olaf in the sense that I'm mentioning the problem you mention, but not try to educate anyone...

Comment: I wonder why I get so many downvotes. Granted, the first answer was wrong and I did not pay attention (that's why it was deleted). But why was this answer downvoted if it works and I haven't seen another possible solution here yet. It doesn't belong in the comment section, but it is really annoying.

Comment: @IshayPeled: My comment stated one reason: you teach bad practice and posibly break the interface on the target machine.

Comment: Let's agree I do not teach anything - only address problems. This is what stackoverflow is for.